# M-Audio Fast Track C400 USB Audio Interface problem

Tags: debian, usb-audio

I`m running Debian 11 on an Asus X750L laptop. I have an M-Audio Fast Track C400 USB Audio Interface. If I restart or shut down the laptop after I turn it on in sound settings there is a signal but there is no sound out on the speakers. Has anyone had a similar experience?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had this same problem and discovered that the interface resets all volume faders to 0 when it is unplugged. I recommend using QasHctl to set the volume on the PCM Out 1 and PCM Out 2 channels. I found that setting PCM Out 1 Channel 1 to max gives left volume and PCM Out 2 Channel 2 Gives Right volume. This will ensure that it is in stereo. If you use both PCM Out 1  channels 1 and 2 it gives you mono.